# VBA copying a range of cells in Excell to a new sheet throws error 2nd time round

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

Hi im writing a method to copy multiple tables into one sheet

the sheet name gets passed to the method

startrow calculates where the first empty row is

it runs through first time and copys first sheet but does not copy subsequent sheets

i get an error saying i can only copy into the first cell og the sheet???

```
Sub WardHandler(SheetName As String)

Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Set TargetSheet = Sheets("TEST")

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Set SourceSheet = Sheets(SheetName)

Dim StartRow As Long
StartRow = 1

If TargetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
StartRow = TargetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If


 With SourceSheet
        .Range("A1", Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy TargetSheet.Cells(StartRow, 1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you go to all the trouble of properly defining the worksheets only to use the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property in `Selection.End(xlDown)` ? The 'second time around' the **SourceSheet** is a different worksheet and Selection is no longer valid.

Comment: Have i done something wrong? its just a way i used before when the number of rows was unknown i was testing using the same source sheet 2nd time round

Comment: You cannot define a range using cells from another worksheet. The first time around, SourceSheet  is the worksheet holding the Selection. The second time it isn't.

Comment: im confused?  and i may not have described the problem very well. if the target sheet has data already there ie. startrow is greater than 1 then the method doesnt even copy first time.

Comment: Where is **Selection** on the first pass?

Comment: is'nt it in whichever sheet.name I pass to the method. you mentioned earlier that source sheet has the selection first time round. but not the second.  but if source sheet is set each time you call the method why does that matter.